# "Could not find this item" every time when renaming, moving, copying! win 7 explorer issue

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm having this issue I noticed is unsolvable around. Everytime I move, copy, rename it prompts ""Could not find this item". Clicking "Try Again" always works but this is bothering and making me waste time. Anybody knows how to solve this? 
I'm on laptop samsung chronos on win7.

Answer (score 8):

At [this answers.microsoft.com site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/renaming-any-folder-produces-could-not-find-this/d907e1d0-648b-4b26-a377-c5116238f336) a user managed to fix the issue by exporting two registry keys from a working installation into his current registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\FolderDescriptions
```

The contents of **his** registry file (yours may differ) are 239 kB, so I can't post them here as an answer. 
If you have a SkyDrive login [you can download that file from here](http://cid-fb5a28bc4a1cc9b6.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/Folder%5E_fix%5E_win7%5E_x64/FolderDescriptions.rar).

Comment: A three year old answer has solved my annoyance! I love SU.

Answer (score 5):

Another method that has worked for me successfully is to delete these registry entries (which unfortunately keep getting added back by some Windows Updates):

1. Open regedit
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\`
3. Under it, delete the following folders (the folder itself):

   - `{2112AB0A-C86A-4ffe-A368-0DE96E47012E}`
   - `{491E922F-5643-4af4-A7EB-4E7A138D8174}`
   - `{7b0db17d-9cd2-4a93-9733-46cc89022e7c}`
   - `{A302545D-DEFF-464b-ABE8-61C8648D939B}`
   - `{A990AE9F-A03B-4e80-94BC-9912D7504104}`
4. Then logoff from your current session and login

This does work, but I would be glad if someone could explain why? And why Microsoft still hasn't fixed this old, repeating bug?

Comment: I can confirm that this works! Indeed it seems I have to do this every time Windows Update runs.

Comment: works for me. had problem after doing some update maintenance. Maybe any, or maybe one of these: -(2830477,2592687,2506143,2574819,2857650,2999226,3102429,3107998,3185319,4474419,4493132,4507004,4516065); +(3163589,3161958,3156019)

Comment: Worked for me also, had this issue after clean install and all windows updates installed.

Comment: This deserves more upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you by any chance disable libraries? In that case, enabling them again fixed this problem for me.  The zip at [AskVG](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-libraries-feature-in-windows-7/) also contains a .reg file to restore the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use cygwin (utility that treats Windows like unix) to delete the file/folder or rename it. Likely there is a trailing space on the end and you'll need to escape it.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

1. Open the directory with the Command Prompt.
2. Type "del " and the file name.

My file names started with some unique string (ark...), so I just typed "del ark*" and it removed it.

Note: This was on Windows Server 2012 R2, but it probably works in Windows 7 as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question.